# Computing the key of a symmetric encryption given the plaintext and ciphertext

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

As part of an assignment I need to make an algorithm that takes 2 files as input, one containing a plaintext and one containing a ciphertext. Considering the encryption model is hardcoded/known, and is a symmetric encryption, is there a way to use openSSL to compute the key used to encrypt the provided plaintext into the provided ciphertext?

For convenience i used 5 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum as a plaintext, and blowfish as the cipher.

The openSSL documentation and Google have proved less than useful.

Thank you!

Comment: http://cryptopals.com/

Comment: The chosen accepted answer has multiple problems and as such should not be the accepted answer. Other answers such as by rossum and SoronelHaetir are correct. Please consider changing the accepted answer to one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.
Not for the blowfish algorithm.

The reason for that is however *not* that *any* encryption scheme would be broken if it were possible to derive the key from a pair of plain text and cipher, even if it is easy to do so.
The rest of this answer is to explain that.

There is at least one encryption scheme which is secure in spite of allowing to derive the key. It is the one-time-pad encryption scheme, which happens to be the only known truly secure encryption scheme, for being proveably unbreakable.
The point is that deriving the key of one message only breaks an encryption scheme, if the knowing the key of one message allows decryption of all future messages. This in turn is only applicable, if the same key is reused.

The specialty of the one-time-pad encryption is

a) each key is used for only a single message and never again
   (this is why it is called "pad", referring to a notepad with many keys, from which the sheet with a used key is easily taken away and destroyed)
b) the key is as long as the message
   (otherwise deriving the key for a part of the cipher with a partial known plain text would allow decrypting the rest of the message)

With those attributes, encrypting even with the humble XOR is unbreakable, each bit in the message corresponding to its own dedicated bit in the key. This is also as fast as de-/encryption gets and never increases the message length.

There is of course a huge disadvantage to the one-time-pad encryption, namely key logistics. Using this encryption is hardly ever applicable, because of the need to provide the receiver of a message with many large keys (or better a very long key which can be used partially for any size of message) and to do so beforehand.
This is the reason for the one-time-pad encryption not being used in spite of the fact that it is safer and faster than all used others and at least as size-efficient.

Other encryption schemes are considered practically secure, otherwise they would of course not be used.
It is however necessary to increase the key sizes in parallel with any noticable progress of crypto-analysis. There is no mathmatical proof that any other algorithm is underivable (meaning it is impossible to derive the key from a plain-cipher-pair). No math expert accepts "I cannot think of any way to do that." proof for something being impossible. On top of that, new technologies could reduce the time for key derivation, or for finding plain text without key, to a fraction, spelling sudden doom to commonly used keylengths.

The symmetry or asymmetry of the algorithm is irrelevant by the way. Both kinds can be derivable or not.

Only the keysize in relation to message length is important. Even with the one-time-pad encryption, a short key (message length being a multiple of key length)
 has to be used more than once. If the first part of a cipherhas a known plain text and allows to derive the key, reusing it allows to find the unknown plain for the rest of the message.
This is also true for block cipher schemes, which change the key for each block, but still allow finding the new key with the knowledge of the previous key, if it is the same. Hybrid schemes which use one (possibly asymmetric) main key to create multiple (usually symmetric) block keys which cannot be derived from each other are, for the sake of this answer, considered derivable if the main key can be derived. There is of course no widely used algorithm for which this is true.

For any scheme, the risk of being derivable increases with the ration of the number of bits in key to the number of bits in the message. The more pairs of cipher bits and plain bits relate to each key bit, the more information is available for analysis. For a one to one relation, restricting the information of one plain-cipher pair to that single pair is possible.

Because of this any derivable encryption requires a key length equal to message length.
In reverse, this means that only non-derivable encryptions can have short keys. And having short keys is of course an advantage, especially if key length implies processing duration. Most encryption schemes take longer with longer keys. The one-time-pad however is equally fast for any key length.

So any algorithm with easy key logistics (no need to agree on huge amounts of keybits beforehand) will be non-derivable. Also any algorithm with acceptable speed will be non-derivable.
Both is true for any widely used algorithm, including blowfish.

It is however not true for all algorithms, especially not for the only truly safe one, the one-time-pad encryption (XOR).

So the answer to your specific question is indeed:
You can't with blowfish and most algorithms you probably think of. But ...

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Stream ciphers will yield the key stream if the cipher is operated with the same security parameters. A simple XOR will do it. There's no need for a trivial or weak cipher. All you need to do is operate the cipher incorrectly by reusing parameters.

Comment: This answer does not address blowfish as the cipher. which was stated in the question. The answer does not define what a "large key" is. Further "Using a small key requires to use it multiple times for a message that is a multiple of the key size" makes no sense.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for your input.

Comment: It is common and usual for a symmetric key, such as used by Blowfish, AES, etc, to be much smaller than the data and this does not reduce the security.  The security is determined by a secure encryption method such as AES and the key size. AES has key sizes of 128, 192 or 256-bits and essentially has no size limit.

Comment: Untrue: "However, a safe symmetric derivable scheme needs a large key." An AES symmetric cipher 128-bit is safe. But is is not clear what "symmetric derivable scheme" means.

Comment: A derivable key has a trivial plain text attack, like a XOR. If however a key (even a derivable key) is as large as the message and only used once (which is practically the definition of the one-time-pad encryption) it is safe. The one-time-pad is safe, to the point of being proovably safe, no matter how much time and power is used for breaking attempts. Only the well know algorithms, e.g. those you mention, are **considered** safe even if they use small keys. The are practically well known **because** they are considered safe, even if small and **not** used once.

Comment: @zaph Would you like to be more careful with describing anything as "untrue" and "it is not clear" at the same time?

Comment: 1. OK, care to explain what "symmetric derivable scheme" means? 2. In general one-time-pads are not used because of the key requirements and difficulty of pre-sharing such a the key. What is of general usable interest are symmetric ciphers such as AES and asymmetric ciphers such as RSA and EC–these are the encryption work horses.

Comment: @zap 1. Yes, I did, already in the older comments, but did with more space in edited answer again 2. True. 3. I edited my answer to highlight the added value compared to the other answers. Thank you for making me aware that it was non-obvious. I also kept a closer eye on the difference of widely used algorithms and the theory of encryption, for which the one-time-pad is very important. Also thanks for that fresh angle.

Answer (score 4):

No, the ability to do that would pretty much defeat the entire purpose of cryptography. There might be tools that can do that sort of thing with trivial systems (Caesar cipher for example) but if keys could be computed in reasonable times for current cryptosystems they would be broken.

Comment: Hello. Not even if the encryption model is symmetrical? I mentioned that in the title but i forgot to mention it in the question as well. Sorry. I edited the question a bit.

Comment: No, remember, in symmetric ciphers the same operation is performed just applying the key to plaintext produces the ciphertext and applying it to the ciphertext produces the plaintext (obviously).Ciphers that can leak the key through known plaintext (even massive numbers of plaintexts) are considered very weak.

Comment: @RaresDima Symmetric encryption is not weak with a suitable key length, an example is AES.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is a "[Known Plaintext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)": if the attacker knows both the ciphertext and the plaintext, can the key be found?

All good modern ciphers, including Blowfish, are designed to resist this attack.  Hence, as has been said, the answer to your question is, "No, you can't find the key."